# Как правильно реализовать работу окон?

Tags: c#, wpf

Первое окно запускается.

Первое окно запускает второе.

Первое передаёт данные второму.

Первое закрывается.

Второе остаётся.

У меня после запуска первого, первое не может получить доступ к переменным и функция второго. Но при этом уже открыты оба.

Есь какой-то пример?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте свойство `Visibility` первого окна

```
window.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```